# Recommend way to use Task.WhenAll to execute tasks in a loop

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, task, task-parallel-library

Can anyone recommend how i can apply [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766.aspx) to the following code

```
foreach (DataRow row in sap_tickets.Rows)
{
    //#EDIT This is the beginning of the task i want to execute
    picklist = row["absentry"].ToString();
    try
    {
         //call webservice here
         string response = await Ut.updateFulfilment(row["order_number"].ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //log error to DB
        Ut.FlagOff(picklist, CommonEnums.FLAG_OFF_TYPE.ERROR.ToString());
    }
    //This is the end of the task i want to execute
}
```

## Edit

My tasks consists of the codes that exists within the foreach loop
and they are safe to call multiple times

Comment: @Edwin: Usually, there's a better way than to use `Task.WhenAll` in a loop. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @stuartd i have edited the question to indicate this

Comment: @StephenCleary i am trying to execute the codes which exists in the body of the foreach loop in a parallel fashion

Comment: If you want to run these at the same time, is `Ut.updateFulfilment(` safe to call multiple times before the first call is done?

Comment: yes @ScottChamberlain it is safe to call multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Ut.updateFulfilment(` is thread safe it is actually pretty easy. Just take the body of the foreach and put it in to an async function then just pass that function in to a `Select(`. Pass the result of the `Select(` in to the `Task.WhenAll(`

```
async Task YourOriginalFunction(DataTable sap_tickets)
{
    //Be user System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll is included in the project refrences 
    //to get AsEnumerable() to work.
    var tasks = sap_tickets.AsEnumerable().Select(BodyAsync)
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

async Task BodyAsync(DataRow row)
{
    picklist = row["absentry"].ToString();
    try
    {
         //call webservice here
         string response = await Ut.updateFulfilment(row["order_number"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //log error to DB
        Ut.FlagOff(picklist, CommonEnums.FLAG_OFF_TYPE.ERROR.ToString());
    }
}
```

You do not do any "heavy lifting" before you hit your first `await` so you don't need to use a `Task.Run(` to get multiple threads, once you issue the webservice request it will immediately start the next loop of the `foreach` instead of waiting for the entire method body to finish before starting the next loop like your old way did.

Comment: i am getting 
System.Data.Datarowcollection does not contain any definition for 'Select' ....at this point 
=> sap_tickets.Rows.Select

Comment: @Edwin I updated the answer, however make sure you have `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` included as a project reference or it wont find the method.

Comment: @Edwin You could also do `sap_tickets.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(` but I like `sap_tickets.AsEnumerable().Select(` because it is a little cleaner.

Comment: things are working, and Catch block is getting executed only once, ideally it should execute 6 times based on the data i am delibrating passing. any ideas why this is happening??

Comment: The catch block will get executed once per entry, perhaps `FlagOff` or `updateFulfilment` is not as thread safe as you thought it was, causing it to not throw when it should?

Comment: There's no reason to use `async/await` in BodyAsync, just return the Task. Also, an ActionBlock would be cleaner and allow control of how many requests can be made concurrently